# how would this non-manifold be rectified? - Split the single surface at its surrounding vertices

Tags: edit-mode

I created a single face with the F key based on a closed loop of edges. It result in a non manifold as it is not split at each of the highlighted vertices. I tried the split option but to no avail.

How can I fix this? Any support is welcome. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the Face->poke faces command ? Or maybe you instead wanted to do a Grid fill instead of <kbd>F</kbd> ?

Comment: I think you mean n-gon instead of non-manifold? Have you tried selecting the n-gon and hitting ctrl+t (triangulate)?

Comment: I have accidentally overwritten the model but thanks for the tips. They are noted.